# Laravel eloquent taking 6-12 seconds to return results

Tags: mysql, laravel, performance, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this data I'm trying to pull, but I have a lot of rows in the DB (over 100k) so it can take 12 secs to return results. Any ideas on how to improve performance?

```
  $completedActivities = Activity::where('executed_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(14))
        ->where('pending', false)
        ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
        ->orderby('executed_at', 'desc')
        ->limit(100)->get();
```

Table structure:

```
Schema::create('activities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('type');
            $table->boolean('pending')->default(true);
            $table->dateTime('pending_until')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('executed_at')->nullable();
            $table->longText('execute')->nullable();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I tried pulling only items from last 14 days (to reduce pulling all activities from db) and tried limiting to 100. any other ideas? refactor maybe?

Comment: What about indices? Can you share the table structure, and add more details about the number of items?

Comment: Does your Activity model contain any preloaded relationships too? It might be that the query is doing more than just that query if it was trying to say load a one-many relationship at the same time. Also you can try logging the raw query to the screen using DB::enableQueryLog(), DB::disableQueryLog(); and DB::getQueryLog()

Comment: @NicoHaase added answers to your questions. over 100K items, see table structure in the question edit. Thanks!

Comment: @simonw16 only a single belongsTo relationship that is not returned in the results array so I don't think it's preloaded.

Comment: This may help a bit : `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');`. Adding a foreign key constraint will definitely decrease load time, but I can't say how much. Worth adding it to find out!

Comment: `$table->index('executed_at')` would be a good start.

Comment: 100k is a really small number of records so it shouldn't be the issue. I usually work with more than 1.5 million records and queries responses are about 0.025 secs. Did you try to run the query directly from some kind of database administrator such as MySQL Workbench?
You need to first figure out if the issue comes from the query or from eloquent.
Are you using Laravel debugbar? It increases significantly the time response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Optimizing SQL Base On EXPLAIN:

Try to use `->toSql()` or `DB::getQueryLog()` to get the raw SQL.

```php
Activity::where('executed_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(14))->where('pending', false)->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->orderby('executed_at', 'desc')->toSql()
```

And use `explain` to see the **Execution Plan** and put them in your MYSQL CLI.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM activities
WHERE user_id = 1 AND pending = false AND executed_at > '2019-11-23 00:00:00'
```

This will show you the table scan message, including **filtered time**, selected **type**, **scan rows**, etc. [Mysql Explain Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html)

## Index Suggestion:

There are two method you can use, it depends on your sql optimizer.

1. I found that you have the `user_id` foreign_key field and scan executed_at field, It seems you need index it. like

```
$table->index('user_id')
$table->index('executed_at')
```

And then use explain to see the results.

2. You have multiple condition. I think you can try the **composite index** to optimize, like

```
$table->index(['user_id', 'executed_at', 'pending'])
```

However, you need to ignore the upper method, if you already have `user_id` index and `executed_at` index, 
you need to drop those index first.

And build this **composite index**, then try this by `explain`.

I think it will improved **for this query, choose this one**.

*PS: Be carefully with order of composite index. Put your `user_id` first, then other simple query can only use `user_id` index, and `explain`, choose the best one.*

And Remember, By default, relational databases ignore NULL values

## Limit data count.

100k+ SQL with index can be scan very easy and fast. 
However you take all results out is a really bad idea.

You need to Limit the **records' count** and the **fields' count**, so that optimizing the IO cost.

```
$completedActivities = Activity::where('executed_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(14))
        ->where('pending', false)
        ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
        ->orderby('executed_at', 'desc')
        # => Limit the records' count, find the balance number fit to frontend
        ->limit(30)               
        # => Limit the fields [Select the fields that you want]
        ->select('id', 'title', ...)    
        ->get();
```

PS: If you are using Laravel's `->paginate()`. It will still use `select count(*) from activities where ...` for getting the total datas count.
You can use `->simplePaginate()` instead.

## Space-saving

I think some fields can be optimized, like space-saving.

It seems `type` is not a long string. You can limit it to a specific length.

```php
$table->string('type', 20);
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: For more efficiency, put the range (`executed_at`) _last_ in the index definition.

Answer (score 0):

after creating indexes you may use build-in simple pagination

```
  $completedActivities = Activity::where('executed_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(14))
        ->where('pending', false)
        ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
        ->orderby('executed_at', 'desc')
        ->simplePaginate(100);
```

simple pagination will not count result records so it will make the query more efficient